# bubble sort problem number of passes (wrong output coming)

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

Write a bubble sort program that prints the number of swaps made after M number of iterations (In this case, ‘M’ should be an input value).

For example, if M = 0, the bubble sort program will perform 0 swaps in 0 iterations.

In bubble sort, an iteration is defined as the total number of times the outer loop runs. Assume that:

1. M <= the array size and
2. the program sorts in descending order.

The code should ask the user to input the values for M, the array size, and finally the elements of the array. So, there will be three types of inputs —

Input 1: The value of M
Input 2: The size of the array
Input 3: The elements inside the array

Sample Input:
2
4
1
2
3
4

Sample Output:
5

Please help me in solving the Bubble Sort Problem. Here I run the program but I am getting 3 in place of 5.

here's my code :

```
package com.company;
    import java.util.*;
    class Source {
        static int totalBubbleSortSwaps(int[] array, int M) {
        int pass=0;
        boolean isDone;
      for (int k = 0; k < ( array.length-1 ); k++) {
            isDone=true;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length-k-1; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j+1])
                {
                    //isDone=false;
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                    pass++;
    
                }
            }
            if(isDone){
                break;
            }
    
        }
        //for (pass =1; pass <m; ++pass){
        //for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
       return pass;
    
    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int m = scanner.nextInt();
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(totalBubbleSortSwaps(array, m));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What value of M are you providing?

Answer (score 1):

> count the number of swaps made after M runs of the outer loop.

A couple observations.

- you are sorting the values in descending order. Is that correct?
- you need to only count the swaps while `m > 0`.
- after each outer loop, decrement `m by 1` (for each iteration of the outer loop).
- you are not setting your `isDone` flag.

Here is what I came up with. I changed `pass` to `swaps`.

```
public class BubbleSort {
    
    static int totalBubbleSortSwaps(int[] array, int m) {
        int swaps = 0;
        boolean isDone;
        for (int k = 0; k < (array.length - 1); k++) {
            isDone = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - k - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {   // <----- changed to > from   <
                     isDone=false;
                    
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                    if (m > 0) {
                        swaps++;    // <---- update swap count
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            if (isDone) {
                break;
            }
            m--;              <---- decrement m
        }
        
        
        return swaps;
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int m = scanner.nextInt();
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(totalBubbleSortSwaps(array, m));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Source {
    static int totalBubbleSortSwaps(int[] array, int m) {
        int swaps = 0;
     for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < array.length - k - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {   
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                swaps++;    
                 }
            }
     }
         return swaps;
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 int m = scanner.nextInt();
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(totalBubbleSortSwaps(array, m));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will give you the number of swaps done in bubble sort (descending order) when "**M**" iterations are done in the outer loop:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BubbleSortSwaps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int M = scanner.nextInt();
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            int array[] = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(totalBubbleSortSwaps(array, M));
        }
    }

    static int totalBubbleSortSwaps(int[] array, int M) {
        int size = array.length;
        int totalSwaps = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            Boolean swap = false;
            for (int j = 1; j < size - i; j++) {
                int swapTemp = 0;
                if (array[j - 1] < array[j]) {
                    swapTemp = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = swapTemp;
                    swap = true;
                    totalSwaps++;
                }
            }
            if (!swap)
                break;
        }
        return totalSwaps;
    }
}
```